# Fading between sprite images without calling out image url in CSS

Tags: html, css, hover, css-transitions, sprite

Is it possible to fade between sprite images on hover without calling out the image URL in the CSS?

I have a ton of two-image sprite sheets. I want each one to switch on hover, but the CSS will be far too bloated if I have to create a new element for every one with a "background: url(*x*)".

```
.frame {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sprite {
  background: url(image.png) 0px 0px no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}

.sprite::after {
  content: "";
  background: url(image.png) -500px 0px no-repeat;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.35s;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.sprite:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity: 0.35s;
}
```

I'd rather call them out here:

```
<div class="sprite frame">
    </div>
```

[Here's a JSFiddle of the effect I want](https://jsfiddle.net/connorwawa/7xc34y8a/), but I want to call out the image URL in the HTML, so I don't have 100 different CSS elements calling out different images.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. If you are open to a jQuery solution this may help. You can use a "data alt-src" HTML attribute to store two image URLs within one tag, then call a jQuery .hover() function on that class.

HTML:

```
<img class="xyz" data-alt src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fatcow/32/accept.png" src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fatcow/32/cancel.png" />
```

jQuery:

```
    var sourceSwap = function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var newSource = $this.data('alt-src');
    $this.data('alt-src', $this.attr('src'));
    $this.attr('src', newSource);
}

$(function () {
    $('img.xyz').hover(sourceSwap, sourceSwap);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LmVRZ/2/

I realize this demo doesn't include the opacity transition but I think it could be built in.

Comment: I achieved a similar solution to that without jQuery by using "object-position," but I'm not sure if opacity transitions are applicable to that because its basically just shifting the spritesheet over.

If possible, I'd like to do it with only CSS/HTML. If not, I'll have to figure something else out. I appreciate you though. Your answer is valuable to me.